# How do I earn Soul Eggs?

Tags: egg-inc

I want to earn more Soul Eggs. I think that I earn one (more like get one more when I prestige) every time this bar gets filled:

[image: soul egg bar]

If that is the case, what do I need to do in order to fill the bar? Also, is there another way to earn Soul Eggs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bar just represents how close you are to the next soul egg.

Soul eggs are actually based on your total prestige earnings. The formula is

`(prestige_earnings / 1,000,000) ^ .14) * epic_soul_egg_prestige_bonus`

You can see your total prestige earnings by clicking: menu -> stats.

Verified by the game developer: https://twitter.com/renderpaz/status/775868514078818304

So anything that makes you more money will increase the amount of soul eggs.

Comment: The formula has since been updated to use a power of 0.15.

Answer (score 3):

You are right. When the bar fills, you will be given one additional soul egg.
The bar increases when you increase you money. This is cummulative, so if you buy an upgrade, the bar won't decrease again.

When you tap drones, watch videos or get a package with money inside, the bar will increase for a bigger amount.

You can also get soul eggs when you fulfill some mission aims.

Answer (score 2):

When your farm gets expensive enough, those will start to go up. I've already restarted once for 110 and can restart again for 201 and am at immortality egg. Also my bar is not full either.

You will also be able to earn few from challenges (I see you have these). I believe it was 6 or something and those were my first soul eggs for some challenge I forgot what it was about.

Basically keep breeding those chickens and keep making those eggs more expensive, you'll get there.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to earn soul eggs is to complete missions. Here's a link to some of the missions and their rewards: http://egg-inc.wikia.com/wiki/Missions

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the Tachyon level and finally realized that your "bar" increases every time you collect from a drone, get a "shipment of cash" or watch a video.

Answer (score 0):

Im at the 6th last Egg and the bar goes faster when the running chicken multiplier is high so I think it’s the amount of money you make